# JQuery disable link/click function not working properly

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

Im trying to make a menu with 2 links with submenu's. The 2 links are disabled by default. When you click on the first link the submenu should show and the link is enabled. This works properly. But when you click on  the second link the "first" link should reset (first link should disable). This is the thing that is not working. After the 2nd link is clicked the first link isn't doing anything at all when clicked. Could somebody help me out with that? I posted the code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="link1" href="link1.html">link1</a></li>
        <li><a class="link2" href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="submenu">
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
</div>
<div id="submenu2">
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(".link2, .link1").bind("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        })

        $( ".link2" ).click(function() {
            $( "#submenu").delay(300).fadeIn();
            $(".link2").unbind("click");
            $( "#submenu2").fadeOut();
            $(".link1").bind("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })

        $( ".link1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#submenu2").delay(300).fadeIn();
            $(".link1").unbind("click");
            $( "#submenu").fadeOut();
            $(".link2").bind("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What about using `.one()`?

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for what you want to achieve. I'm not sure though. I really don't know what you want to achieve. Please clearify what you want to achieve and update your question with html etc.

Comment: You appear to have an extra `}` at the end of your code.

Comment: Using .one(), will keep me the same problem I think. Because the link should be able to switch between enabled / disabled many times and not just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to unbind the click events ?

I guess you don't want the animation to start again. But, you got to know that the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` will not. If the element is already shown, the `fadeIn` will do nothing. Neither the `fadeOut` if the element is already hidden.

And you should use the fadeOut callback function, instead of `delay(300)`. It is nicer.

Then, you could simply do :

```
$( ".link1" ).click(function(e) {
    $( "#submenu2").fadeOut(function(){
        $( "#submenu").fadeIn();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}); 

$( ".link2" ).click(function(e) {
    $( "#submenu").fadeOut( function(){
          $( "#submenu2").fadeIn(); 
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t78FJ/3/)

---

If you really want to block a second click on the same link, you got to use a flag to save the element state. Save it in the dataset of each `submenu`.

With something like that :

```
$( ".link1" ).click(function(e) {
    if (!$("#submenu").data('visible')) {
        $( "#submenu2").fadeOut( function(){
            $( "#submenu").fadeIn().data('visible',true);
        }).data('visible',false);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}); 

$( ".link2" ).click(function(e) {
    if (!$("#submenu2").data('visible')) {
        $( "#submenu").fadeOut(function(){
            $( "#submenu2").fadeIn().data('visible',true);
        }).data('visible',false);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See this other [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t78FJ/4/)

You could use the `.is(":hidden")` selector, but it will fail if the click appends while  the last animation is still running.

Comment: Not really what i meant. When the submenu of link 1 is shown, you should be able to click on link 1 and go to that page (the submenu's are hidden by default). Idem for link 2. Thank you for your reaction though.

Comment: @Chivandos : In that case, choose the second solution because you need a flag and put the `e.preventDefault();` inside the `if` instructions. See updated jsFiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/t78FJ/37/

Comment: @Chivandos: You are welcome. But I think you forgot to 'check' me and upvot my solution. I take car of my stats dude ;)